# express.bodyParser not parsing?

Tags: node.js, express

I've stripped everything down to the absolute bare bones to try and fine out whats wrong, and still can't get bodyParser to do anything. It won't even work for .txt files.

*server.js*

```
var     cfg     = require(__dirname + '/config'),
    express     = require('express');


var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.logger(cfg.LOGGER));
app.use(require('connect').bodyParser());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
    res.end();
});

app.post('/upload', function(req,res) {
    console.log(req.body.file);
    res.end();
});

app.listen(2017);
```

*index.ejs*

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload" method="POST">
    <input id="multipart/form-data" type="file" name="foo" />
    <button>Upload</button>
</form>
```

the result is that `req.body.file` is `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the file using `req.files.<yourFileInputFieldName>`:

```
console.log(req.files.foo);
```

More info in [this section](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.files) of the docs.

Comment: Ya I know that. One of those things were at this point - I just want to know why the above *doesn't* work. I'll mark your answer as correct anyway since nobody else will likely respond. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @ColinMartell It doesn't work because `files` are simply provided apart from `res.body`. The separation comes from [formidible](https://npmjs.org/package/formidable), which supplies `fields` (`body`) and `files` separately to the [`multipart` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/multipart.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
  app.use(require('connect').bodyParser());
            as
  app.use(express.bodyParser());  


  app.post('/upload', function(req,res) {
     console.log(req.body.foo);//in req.body u have to mention the name of the file..
     res.end();
  });
```

Comment: req.body is an empty object